# How to unit test an Angular 1.5 Component template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So, here's my test:

```
describe('My Test', function(){

  var $componentController, $compile, controller, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $rootScope, $templateCache){

    $templateCache.put('my-component.html', '<h1>{{ $ctrl.foo }}</h1>');

    $componentController = $injector.get('$componentController');

    var bindings = {
      foo: 'A Foo'
      };

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    controller = $componentController('myComponent', { $scope: {} }, bindings);

    }));

  it('should render the correct html', function(){

    scope.foo = 'Changed Foo';

    var element = angular.element(
      '<my-component foo="Original Foo"></my-component>'
      );

    var template = $compile(element)(scope);

    scope.$digest();

    var templateAsHtml = template.html();

    console.log(templateAsHtml);

    };

}
```

And what I get is **"Original Foo"**, not **"Changed Foo"**. So, even if I change the `scope.foo` variable in my test, it uses the one on the component (or on the controller).

So any idea on how to change the component variables on the test, so when I compile the template it catches those changes.

Basically what I want is to be able to access and modify the controller variables, so then I can test certain output depending on the controller variables values. Does this make sense?

Comment: You did not post the code for the component, it is necessary here. It is hard to believe that `{{ foo }}` results in `Original Foo`, because component template is supposed to use `$ctrl.foo` (or whatever controllerAs is).

Comment: The component template uses `$ctrl.foo` (I already change that on the post) and the bindings are the same as the ones I put on the test, so there's no need to put that extra code in here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scope.foo` doesn't affect component bindings. `foo` scope property is not `foo` attribute.

This likely should be tested like

```
var component = $compile('<my-component foo="{{ foo }}">')(scope);

scope.$digest();

var componentScope = component.isolateScope();

expect(component.html())...
expect(componentScope.$ctrl.foo)...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it's not working for me. Actually if I do a `console.log(componentScope.$ctrl.foo);` what I get is the original value that is set on the component controller. Basically what I want is to be able to access and modify the controller variables, so then I can test certain output depending on the controller variables values. Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't think that this adds value to the test. Testing for original value is enough. By testing 'changed value' you're trying to test not your own code but Angular compiler, which was already tested by Angular team. I guess it could be possible to do that *after* `$compile(...)(scope); scope.$digest()` with `scope.foo = ...; scope.$digest()`. Then `componentScope.$ctrl.foo` should be equal to `scope.foo`. But again, this is totally unnecessary.

Comment: That was just an example, actually I didn't post all my real code. But anyway, you gave me an idea of how to modify the component scope variables by using `componentScope.$ctrl.foo = 'new value'`  then modifying the variables that I need, followed with a `scope.$digest`then I can just use `expect(component.find('button').length).toEqual(2)` (or whatever condition I need to test)

Comment: Actually, `$compile` and `$componentController` and are two orthogonal approaches. `$componentController` is supposed to do purely 'unit' testing. `$compile` is more 'functional' approach, only `scope` should be changed and `componentScope.$ctrl` can be asserted if needed. I would suggest to not mix these approaches.